# How to remove a specific line that contains a specific string?

Tags: python

I have tried some codes myself based off of codes I found online but none seems to be working.

The text file contains something as such:

```
Student ID: 1230345

Course code:FHCT1024
Grade: A
GPA: 4.0000

CGPA :4.0000
```

and I want to delete the line with the string `'CGPA'` in it. I tried using:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as inp, open("file.txt", 'w') as f:
    for line in inp:
        if line.strip().startswith("CGPA"):
            pass
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

But this deleted everything.

Comment: Opening a file in `'w'` mode destroys the existing contents.

Comment: You can't read and write to a file simultaneously (easily). Either write the results to a temporary file and rename it after deleting the original, or store the results in memory and rewrite the original file afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the lines while you are reading the file

```
res = []

with open("file.txt", 'r') as inp:
            for line in inp:
                if line.strip().startswith("CGPA"):
                    pass
                else:
                    res += [line]
```

`res` will contain all the `lines` that do not start with "CGPA".

Once you have `res` , you can write it to a file if needed

Answer (score 1):

```
text='''Student ID: 1230345

Course code:FHCT1024
Grade: A
GPA: 4.0000

CGPA :4.0000'''

text_ls=text.splitlines()

for i in range(len(text_ls[:])):
    if text_ls[i].startswith('CGPA'):
        text_ls.remove(text_ls[i])
print('\n'.join(text_ls))
```

Comment: yes this gave a clear concept thanks man

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose of your program is delete the line starting with `CGPA`, I would suggest you to look at `sed` command.

```
sed '/^CGPA/d' file.txt
```

This is much faster and needs lesser number of lines of code.

Comment: I will have a look into sed thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's open in append mode ('a'):

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as inp, open("file.txt", 'a') as f:
            for line in inp:
                if line.strip().startswith("CGPA"):
                    pass
                else:
                    f.write(line)
```

Comment: This appended the text without the CGPA line so if it was in write mode it would work i think thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that youre reading to the same file youre writing, this can lead to problems, because as youre reading the file the data is changing and is dynamic. Then you can try naming the file youre writing on differently. Here you have your input file named file.txt. Then name your output file "fileoutput.txt".

Also you can search for different opening file modes such as '+r' and others that can make this process easier.

But this should work:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as inp, open("fileoutput.txt", 'w') as f:
            for line in inp:
                if line.strip().startswith("CGPA"):
                    pass
                else:
                    f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read, update, then write; I would recommend breaking that up into two distinct `open` context managers: one for read and one for write because flat is easier to grok than nested. Also, you may want to write to a different file in order to preserve the original.

```py
lines_without_cgpa = []

with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "CGPA" not in line and "" != line:
            lines_without_cgpa.append(line)

print(lines_without_cgpa)

with open("file_without_cgpa.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines_without_cgpa)
```